# How does AucTeX display superscripts?

Tags: auctex, faces, text-properties

`latex-mode` is has a nice display of superscripts and subscripts. Not
only are they reduced in size, but they are respectively raised and
lowered a bit relative to the current line.

**Q:** How can I make part of the text in a line look like a superscript?

I know how to make text small (with the `height`face property), but I
don't know how to raise it. I tried to investigate `latex-mode`, but
all I could find was that `font-latex-superscript-face` had a small
`height` property (which doesn't account for the raising).

Comment: (meekly says `hello` to the first question posted from `sx.el`)

Answer (score 7):

Use the `raise` display property.  As explained in `(info "(elisp) Other Display Specs")`:

```
`(raise FACTOR)'
     This kind of display specification raises or lowers the text it
     applies to, relative to the baseline of the line.

     FACTOR must be a number, which is interpreted as a multiple of the
     height of the affected text.  If it is positive, that means to
     display the characters raised.  If it is negative, that means to
     display them lower down.

     If the text also has a `height' display specification, that does
     not affect the amount of raising or lowering, which is based on the
     faces used for the text.
```

For AUCTeX specifically, this behavior is effected by `font-latex-script` and controlled by `font-latex-script-display`.

Comment: There is also `:ascent`, apparently.

Comment: [`font-latex-script-display`](https://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex/Fontification-of-math.html) does, indeed, use the `raise` display property.